# How to change the file names in NextJs when building

Tags: webpack, next.js, output, filenames

When I build it, I get a file name like 108-b9dae8c2869cb767.js. Can I change the name to something like app.212.js. I mean those files that are stored in .next => static .... Except that you also need to set a meaningful name for the css files

My next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  generateBuildId: async () => 'build-id',
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules = [
      ...config.module.rules,
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
            options: {
              svgo: true,
              titleProp: true,
              svgoConfig: {
                plugins: [
                  {
                    name: 'preset-default',
                    params: {
                      overrides: {
                        removeViewBox: false,
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        generator: {
          filename: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ]
    return config
  },
}
```

I also tried the same thing `config.output.filename = '[name].js';` , but it didn't work.